PlaceHolder.Controls doesn't have anything even though I added to it
I'm using ASP.NET with html/css and in one part of my code I have:
CoursesListLit.Controls.Add(list);

list is a radioButtonList and CoursesListLit is a PlaceHolder control.
In another part, I have this line of code:
RadioButtonList list = (RadioButtonList)CoursesListLit.FindControl("CoursesList");

and it can't find any control with ID coursesList (I double checked a million times the ID is indeed CoursesList and I did set it to be like that).
RadioButtonList list = new RadioButtonList();
list.ID = "CoursesList";

This is how I set the ID, why isn't it working?
I tried to using CoursesListLit.Controls[0], it said out of index error, basically the add "doesn't do anything" (it does for the front end though so that's why I'm confused)

Well, the first question is any reason why you can't just have that control in the markup? Remember, when you add controls to a webform page, then the code behind class ALSO creates a reference to that control. This is how .net resolves controls on that page using code behind. If you are using code to add controls (and it NOT clear why you need to do this), then such controls can only be used by code behind using .findcontrol, since the page class is created at design time, and not at run time (compile time). You have to make a great case why you using code to add controls to the page.

Please share a [mcve].

@AlbertD.Kallal Well I can't have it in the markup because I need to to dynamically change...

Change what? You are free as a bird to change the radio button list from code behind.

@AlbertD.Kallal I need to add list items dynamically I can do it from the behind code?
